# Appium - Setup proxy server on mobile Android and iOS devices

Tags: ios, ssl, proxy, appium, appium-ios

I need to be able to capture HTTP(S) requests from Android and iOS devices, for both Browsers and, in the future, for Native apps for testing purposes mainly.

Some aspects to consider:

- There are a lot of devices/iOS combinations to support, so the only viable solution is to use a Cloud Browser provider like SauceLabs, BrowserStack, etc.
- Preferably, I would use Real devices, not Emulators/Simulators
- We could make any kind of tweaks for the staging environment of the site under test in case is needed
- Same for the native applications

My first attempt was to give it a try with FiddlerCore, and while it works on Android, it doesn't work on iOS because of the self-signed certificate that would require to be trusted manually (leaving aside the fact that due to security reasons, no Cloud Browser provider would allow you to do it).

So, next I thought of creating a proxy server and buying a Trusted CA Signed Certificate (e.g. Comodo, GoDaddy, etc), setup the device to use that proxy server and then fetch in my tests the requests and responses from it.

I don't know much about Certificates and don't have extensive experience Appium, so the following questions arise:

- Will the setup mentioned above, using a proxy server and trusted CA signed cert suffice for iOS not to complain that the certificate is not trusted? Note that I won't be able to manually accept the cert on the device (in case it's needed).
- In case the setup above will work, is it possible to setup using Appium the proxy settings on the device? As far as I know, Appium can interact with Android Settings menu, but I'm not sure about iOS.
- Is there anything that I missed or that I could keep mind?

Comment: Just a thought, would it not be easier to capture the packets on the server (if you have access to the machine) with something like `wireshark`?

Comment: That would be easier indeed, however I'm interested in analytics requests and responses, and they differ based on the client device where they're rendered.

Comment: @Cosmin were you able to find a solution ?